# What 7-letter word am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My first two refer to that boy.
>   My first three refer to that girl.
>   My first four refer to that boy being brave.
>   My whole refers to that girl being brave.

Not a very difficult puzzle, but it's from a book I loved as a kid, so I figured that someone else might enjoy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> Heroine.

As

> He-Her-Hero-Heroine, the female form of hero.